# Find isomorphism of two graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for an isomorphism of these two graphs. How can I go about doing so? Finding equivalent vertices would be a good strategy for a small graph but these have 10 vertices.

[image]

Comment: @avs It's a good strategy in general, but in this case all vertices have degree 3!

Answer (score 1):

A graph isomorphism preserves edge connections. One such isomorphism between these graphs is in the picture I have uploaded below. Sorry for my bad drawings!

[image]